# ¿Cómo validar si un archivo PDF está protegido, y de estarlo, omitirlo y no leerlo?

Tags: c#, pdf, itextsharp

Tengo un archivo PDF convertido a un arreglo de bytes `byte[]` y empleo `ITextShart PdfReader` para leer su contenido.

Cuando el archivo está protegido, mi código lanza una excepción. Lo que quiero es ser capaz de realizar una validación antes de leer el archivo, donde, en caso de estar protegido omitirlo, no leerlo, ya que no cuento con la clave para desproteger dicho archivo.

En la segunda línea obtengo la excepción cuando el archivo está protegido:

```
public static string StampAllPagesPdfFromImage(string base64, byte[] dataImagen)
{
   byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
   PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no simplemente cachas las excepción?

Comment: Si se me ocurrió meter el código dentro de un try catch pero sería la última opción, si existe una forma de poder validar para que no se generé el error. Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué te incomoda del try-catch?

Comment: A mí tampoco me gusta validar por medio de try/catch, pero a veces no queda otra. Y creo que es tu caso, porque si con tan solo instanciar el `PdfReader` ya te da error, no hay mucho más que hacer.

Comment: Puede que te sirva: [Opening password-protected pdf file with iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666577/opening-password-protected-pdf-file-with-itextsharp)